# Issues migrating a bare git repository to a new machine

Tags: git

Update to this Question:

It seems that a shared folder was never created for the parent directory that the repository was stored in. Once this shared folder was created, I was able to access the repo. This issue is resolved. See below for details:

---

I have a bare git repository hosted on a machine that holds an automation project. The old machine is being replaced with a new machine and will be decommissioned after the new machine is set up. I need to move the git repository from the old machine to the new machine, preserving the git history if possible.

I've tried simply copy/pasting the parent directory the repository is stored in from the old machine to the new machine. Everything seems to be copied over fine, but I am unable to access the git repository remotely after updating the remote origin to the new destination. I've also tried a git clone (and git clone --mirror), and have also had no luck in being able to access the repository remotely.

On the old machine, to access the repository remotely, the URL would look like the following:

```
\\hostname\parent-directory\git-repository.git
```

The error messages I receive when attempting to connect to the repository are as follows:

```
\\hostname\parent-directory\git-repository.git does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I understand that IP and SSH connections might be usable here, but I would still like to keep the hostname in the URL for uniformity if possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the error message(s) you are getting when you try to connect? This could be due to file permissions, network connections and many other things. We'll need more information to figure it out.

Comment: @joanis - I updated the question above with the error messages I have been receiving. I do know that it is a git repository, since I can go to the file location and perform git operations there.

Comment: I have to agree with @SebDieBln, this is almost certainly a permission issue.

Comment: That's what we've been thinking as well, I just wanted to make sure that I wasn't missing anything simple! Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Your URL `\\hostname\parent-directory\git-repository.git` looks like a SMB-share so you are probably using the [local protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols). Without knowing the exact error message you get I strongly suggest checking for **access problems of the SMB-share**. Probably the new machine does not have a samba service running or the share is not configured properly.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I'll go ahead and check with the network team to see if there's anything configurations that may not be configured properly.